# How to resolve open generic service without registering type object?

Tags: autofac, asp.net5

I am trying to figure out how to resolve for a generic service without registering the type.  I need to do this at runtime as there are too many different types that will need to be passed to this service and several others.

I used RegisterAssemblyTypes to register several services.  One of those services is MongoService, which is registered as MongoService<>.

I see the service listed in list of the scope's registrations.  When I attempt to resolve the service as

```
_productService = diScope.Resolve<MongoService<Product>>(new NamedParameter("mongoSettings", productCollection));
```

I get the ComponentNotRegisteredException below:

```
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The requested service 'RecWebEditor.Services.MongoService`1[
  [bn.pds.ren.RENAPI.objects.ren.Product, RENAPI, Version=2020.2.4.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
   has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(),
    or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
  Source=Autofac
```

I know that Autofac doesn't have the Product type registered, since I have not registered it.

I was expecting this to get resolved the same way as the Microsoft Logging ILogger.

I suspect I am missing something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few things of note here:

- You can't resolve something that isn't registered.
- As of today (Feb. 2, 2021) you can't register open generics using assembly scanning. [It's a PR actively being worked, so it's coming](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/pull/1246) but it's not here.

I think the answer is going to be:

Instead of registering `MongoService<T>` using assembly scanning, [use the open generics registrations](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components). It'll look something like this, but **read the docs I linked** to get more understanding. This is an example of what it *might* look like, not copy/paste ready for the needs of your app.

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MongoService<>))
       .AsSelf();
```

After that, see if you can resolve your `MongoService<Product>`. I don't think when you register an open generic using those extensions that you have to register the `T` inside the `MongoService<T>`.

[Here are some example unit tests](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/test/Autofac.Specification.Test/Registration/OpenGenericTests.cs) showing the generic registrations in action, in case you want to see more real code.

Comment: Thank you.  That was the issue. Just wished it was noted in the docs.

Comment: I've [added an issue to the docs on your behalf.](https://github.com/autofac/Documentation/issues/134)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the below is overly simplified, but it works for to scan the assembly and then register the generics.

```
protected void RegisterGenericServices(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly executingAssembly)
{
    var services = executingAssembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IService))
                    && t.IsGenericType);

    foreach (var service in services) builder.RegisterGeneric(service).AsSelf();
}
```

I will end up with too many services that will need to be registered.

Once again, thank you.